# Perl Net::SSH2 in pty mode and EOF

Tags: perl, ssh, eof, pty

I am using perl Net::SSH2 v0.48 and trying to execute a remote script which reads input from stdin. The channel of this connection is using vt100 pty for some specific requirements. After writing data to stdin I am also calling `$channel->send_eof();`. But the remote script doesn't seem to receive any EOF character at all. The remote script is in python and reading from stdin like `sys.stdin.read()` and it hangs until it gets an EOF. This problem simply gets solved when either I disable pty or append `chr(4)` with input payload which is the EOF character.

Questions:

1. Any idea why `send_eof()` is not working?
2. What is the best way to solve this problem?
3. Can I assume that `send_eof()` is not required if pty is enabled?

P.S. I am not including any code snippet right now because the production code is too complex to explain the problem and it will take some time to prepare a working version of minimal code. But I will try to update my question with a code sample soon.

Comment: Version 0.48 is quite old and buggy. You should use a more recent one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I assume that send_eof() is not required if pty is enabled?

From [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2::Channel#send_eof):

> **send_eof**
>
> Sends an EOF to the remote side.
>
> After an EOF has been sent, no more data may be sent to the remote
>   process STDIN channel.
>
> Note that **if a PTY was requested for the channel, the EOF may be ignored by the remote server.**

Comment: `EOF may be ignored by the remote server`, doesn't it mean that the EOF may be ignored even if I append that as a part of my input data? Obviously that's not happening but it seems like there might be some more information to get the full picture.

Comment: Tty devices do not allow to close just one side of the connection. That's why EOF requests at the channel level are ignored.